# Library method returns nothing

Tags: solidity

When using the `using foo for type` syntax, the methods of a type will return an empty tuple instead of the explicit type defined within the library. Why?

Currently using Solc v0.3.2.

Example:

```
library foo {
    // Should Return a string
    function greet(string storage self) returns (string) {
        return "Hello";
    }
}

contract Greeter {

    using foo for string;
    string name = "lary";

    function say() constant returns (string) {
        return name.greet();
    }
}
```

Returns:

```
// Error: Different number of arguments in return statement 
// name.greet => type function (string storage pointer) returns ()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a problem of libraries in themselves, but a general problem with the Ethereum virtual machine: It is practically impossible to return data of variable size in external function calls.

Having said that, we are just about to merge a change this week that might help you: If you change the library function to `internal`, your function will work. What will happen behind the scenes is that the call to `greet` will be converted from an external function call into an internal function call (where returning variably-sized data is possible because memory is not cleared between the calls). This has a drawback, though: For this to be possible, the library function code will be compiled into the calling contract, which is something you might want to avoid especially for large functions.

Comment: Thank you for following up, I didn't see the solidity docs mention anything about this, shouldn't this be an issue?